# Logitech ConferenceCam Connect Freezes Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, intel, webcam, soundcard, logitech

Complete novice here. Haven't used ubuntu in years.

I have a Logitec ConferenceCam Connect. Works fine on Window and Chrome OS. As soon as I plug it into Ubuntu the system freezes and becomes unresponsive. As soon as I unplug it all becomes fine again. Tested on fresh installs of Mate 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 after performing all updates.

No idea where to start to fix this.

Edit: It seems to have something to do with the audio. I can switch the video component of the camera/mic/speaker combo off but even so after about 30sec the system freezes. And it is picked up as an external sound card.

Edit: System log at time of error:

```
3
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 1623.488198] usb 2-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 44
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 1623.490070] usb 2-1.2: clear tt 1 (02c0) error -71
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 1623.494118] usb 2-1.2.1: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name pulseaudio[1713]: [pulseaudio] udev-util.c: Failed to get card object.
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name pulseaudio[1713]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.1/2-1.2.1:1.2
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name pulseaudio[1713]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-Logitech_ConferenceCam_Connect_0X450X090XCB0X15-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-Logitech_ConferenceCam_Connect_0X450X090XCB0X15-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.1/2-1.2.1:1.0
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 15
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.1/2-1.2.1:1.1
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 16
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 1623.627156] usb 2-1.2.2: USB disconnect, device number 45
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.1/2-1.2.1:1.3/0003:046D:084C.0018
Aug 11 11:02:09 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.1/2-1.2.1:1.3
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.1
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2/2-1.2.2:1.1
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2/2-1.2.2:1.0
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2/2-1.2.2:1.2/0003:046D:084B.0019
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2/2-1.2.2:1.2
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2
Aug 11 11:02:10 barry-System-Product-Name upowerd[1208]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install Ubuntu 16.04. That made my setup work.

Comment: This seems like something one would try only as a last resort. Can you clarify the details of your setup? Was your problem the same?

Comment: I have same hardware and tried all options. It do seam though that maybe Kernel 5.9 solves this. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203419#c49, but I have not tested that yet.

Comment: Good find - you can update your answer if you manage to find time to test that :)